# Write output of linear dynamical system in terms of adjugate matrix

Tags: dynamical-systems, laplace-transform

I'm trying to understand a statement given by a book ("Analysis and Design of Autonomous Microwave Circuits", Almudena Suarez). It defines a linear dynamical system in the Laplace domain as $sX=AX+GU$ or equivalently $(sI-A)X=G(s)U(s)$ where $X$ is a vector of system states, $A$ is the system matrix, $U$ is a vector with inputs to the system, $G$ is a matrix that combines the inputs in some manner, and $s$ is the Laplace variable.

With zero input to the system ($U=0$), we can write $(sI-A)X=0$ from which we obtain the characteristic polynomial of the system, $P(s)=det(sI-A)$.

The textbook then states that some output of the system can be written as $$Y(s)=B(sI-A)^+$$ where the "+" denotes the transpose of the cofactor matrix and $B$ is some matrix. *This is where I get confused. My understanding is that the transpose of the cofactor matrix is called the adjugate, but I'm not sure what significance the adjugate has in this context.*

The book goes further to state in the case of a single-input, single-output system (ie $U$ and $Y$ are both scalar), then we can write the transfer function of this system as
$$H(s)=\frac{Y(s)}{U(s)}=\frac{B(sI-A)^+G}{P(s)}$$

*I'm having trouble understanding how the author goes from the definitions of $U$ and $Y$ to obtain the transfer function.*

Comment: Similar formula appear in the notes [here](https://faculty.washington.edu/chx/teaching/me547/1-5_ss2tf_slides.pdf). In that source, however, they introduce the adjugate because $M^+ =M^{-1}\det(M)$. Hence the factor $(sI-A)^+/P(s)$ is equivalent to $(sI-A)^{-1}$, which is probably useful.

Comment: @Semiclassical Thanks for the reference, that really helped answer my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Semiclassical for providing a source that led to an answer.

Essentially, we can write the following:
$$sX=AX+GU$$
$$Y=BX$$

Then we can solve for $X$ in the first equation:
$X=(sI-A)^{-1}GU$

and substitute into the second equation: $Y=B(sI-A)^{-1}GU$

Finally, we write the transfer function as
$$H=\frac{Y}{U}=B(sI-A)^{-1}G=\frac{B(sI-A)^+G}{det(sI-A)}=\frac{B(sI-A)^+G}{P(s)}$$

Regarding the invertibility of $(sI-A)$, we look at whether $P(s)$ is zero or not. Since $P(s)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A$, it is clearly only zero when $s$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, or in this case a pole of the system. So this behavior is expected.